# How to import existing project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I am importing a eclipse project into android studio . All steps are fine but at the end it asks for eclipse workspace path and its giving error like.

Cant Save Settings

Enter a value for workspace path /src/com/magtek/mobile/android/demo/EMVLanguage.java

Comment: The workplace path is a folder not a Java file.

Comment: try removing EMVLanguage.java then try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import project from eclipse to android studio like following steps:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project.
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.
4. Select the destination folder and click Next.

Please read this link. It might be helpful to you.

[Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah i am doing same way but on last its asking like that as i mentioned in my question "Enter a value for workspace path /src/com/magtek/mobile/android/demo/EMVLanguage.java"  don't know why

Comment: I have same above steps for my eclipse project.its working.which android studio version you are using?

Comment: Android Studio 2.0

Comment: I am using 2.2 and i follow above steps.its working fine.can you select androidmanifest.xml path when imprt project in studio?

Comment: then no other step for further project import.

Answer (score 1):

How to import new project to Android Studio
Once you have unzip the file make sure 
you delete duplicates of actual folder name
e.g QuakeReport-> QuakeReport ->app,.gradle,build, e.t.c

delete the duplicate  sub file which it should be like this below

QuakeReport-> ->app,.gradle,build, e.t.c

then copy this file build.gradle file from your past android project into this project or visit https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html search for

dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'}

which you copy other codes located in that block of code only and name your file
build.gradle

Open your Android Studio
Click on File located at the left upper end of Android Studio
click on New file
Scroll to Import file
Select the file
Click on import
Click on import project from external model
Click on use local gradle distribution then select latest gradle
gradle file is often located at
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-4.1
then follow other on screen instruction

if after you have done all that and the run(play button) is not active
or you see an on screen message gradle not present in this project
Click on clean project
then click on rebuild project
then there will be a message at event log
scroll if it is update gradle needed click on it and update
Gradle will be active

Answer (score 0):

Click on Build.gradle of the application and select open with android studio