# importing existing project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble importing an existing project

How can I do it?

Comment: You just open the Gradle file... What issues are you having?

Comment: Refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760904/how-to-import-existing-project-in-android-studio

Comment: should all directories be imported or only android.I am in android studio

Comment: What exactly is the trouble/error/msg etc.?
Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

go to file->new->import project